# Autoconf with boost test - linker issue

Tags: c++, boost, linker, autotools, undefined-reference

I'm facing an issue with boost unit_test framework along with autoconf & automake...

**Here's about the project structure:**

- ./include/com_i_foo.h
- **./include/com_foo.h**

```
    ...
    class FooSingleton {
    protected:
    FooSingleton() {}
    private:
    FooSingleton* _instance;
    public:
    virtual ~FooSingleton() {}
    static FooSingleton* getInstance();
    };

    class FooFoo {
    public:
    FooFoo() {}
    virtual uint32_t getSomeInt();
    virtual ~FooFoo() {}
    };
    typedef boost::shared_ptr FooFooPtr_t;
    ...
```

- **./include/com_api.h**

```
    #include "com_foo.h"
```

- **./include/Makefile.am**

```
    include_HEADERS = \
            com_i_foo.h \
            com_foo.h \
            com_api.h \
            $(NULL)
```

- ./src/com_foo.cpp
- **./src/Makefile.am**

```
    PLATEFORM=LINUX64
    DEBUG_OPTIONS = -g
    DEFINE_OPTIONS=-D${PLATEFORM}
    OPTIONS = -Wall -Werror -shared -O2 $(DEBUG_OPTIONS) $(DEFINE_OPTIONS)

    COMMON_CXXFLAGS= ${OPTIONS} -I$(top_builddir)/include
    ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I ${top_builddir}/m4
    AM_LDFLAGS=

    lib_LTLIBRARIES  = \
            libcom_api.la \
            $(NULL)

    libcom_api_la_SOURCES = com_foo.cpp
    libcom_api_la_CXXFLAGS = ${COMMON_CXXFLAGS}
    libcom_api_la_LDFLAGS =
    libcom_api_la_LIBADD =
```

- **./test/Makefile.am**

```
    PLATEFORM=LINUX64
    DEBUG_OPTIONS = -g
    DEFINE_OPTIONS=-D${PLATEFORM} -DBOOST_ENABLE_ASSERT_HANDLER
    OPTIONS = -Wall -Werror -O2 $(DEBUG_OPTIONS) $(DEFINE_OPTIONS)

    BOOST_LIBS = -lboost_unit_test_framework -lboost_locale -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lboost_thread

    COMMON_CXXFLAGS= ${OPTIONS} -I$(top_srcdir)/include -I$(top_srcdir)/src
    AM_LDFLAGS=
    ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I ${top_builddir}/m4

    check_PROGRAMS = ut_com_api

    ut_com_api_SOURCES = \
            ut_com_api.cpp \
            $(NULL)
    ut_com_api_CXXFLAGS = ${COMMON_CXXFLAGS}
    ut_com_api_LDFLAGS = -rdynamic
    ut_com_api_LDADD = ${BOOST_LIBS} $(top_builddir)/src/libcom_api.la
```

- **./test/ut_com_api.cpp**

```
    #define BOOST_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC
    #define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
    #define BOOST_TEST_MODULE "Common API Unit tests"

    #include 

    #include "com_api.h"

    using namespace boost::unit_test;

    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(com_api)

    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(FooFooTest) {
    FooFooPtr_t myFoo(new FooFoo());
    BOOST_CHECK(myFoo->getSomeInt() == 2);
    }

    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(FooSingletonTest) {
    FooSingleton* myFoo = FooSingleton::getInstance();
    BOOST_CHECK(myFoo != NULL);
    }

    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

- **./Makefile.am**

```
    SUBDIRS = include src test
    #dist_doc_DATA = README
    ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4
```

- **./configure.ac**

```
    AC_INIT([com_api], [1.0], [bug@foo.foo])
    AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])
    AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror foreign])
    AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
    AC_PROG_CXX
    AC_LANG_PUSH(C++)
    AX_BOOST_BASE([1.53], ,[AC_MSG_ERROR([You need boost library])])
    AX_BOOST_PROGRAM_OPTIONS
    AX_BOOST_DATE_TIME
    AC_CHECK_HEADER([boost/shared_ptr.hpp], , [AC_MSG_ERROR([You need boost library])])
    AC_LANG_POP(C++)
    AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
    AC_CONFIG_FILES([
    Makefile
    include/Makefile
    src/Makefile
    test/Makefile
    ])
    AC_OUTPUT
```

**My Problem**:

When I build the  DLL (.so under linux) it works perfectly, but when I try to build the check_PROGRAMS, the linker returns the following undefined references:

- undefined reference to FooSingleton::_instance
- **In function `boost::shared_ptr::operator->() const':
  undefined reference to boost::assertion_failed(char const*, char const*, char const*, long)**

About FooSingleton, I don't understand why because I'm well linking my check program with the built dll...

About boost, I guess I'm lacking a -lboost_xxxx in my test/Makefile.am, but I don't get why I'd have to explicitly specify boost libs to the linker for check_PROGRAMS while it works perfectly with the DLL build...

I've looked everywhere for a solution, but I'm running out of ideas so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There's a way to define the singleton to bypass this issue, but it'd still be nice to understand the issue:
static StatisticManager &getInstance() {
  static StatisticManager instance;
  return instance;
}
I'm still facing boost undefined reference!

Comment: Is all the autotools boilerplate relevant here? If so, you might want to add a tag so someone familiar with that environment sees this question. If not, please reduce the code down to just what is needed. It isn't obvious to me what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: My intention was to provide as much as I could so that there is enough information to find the issue but I get your point. I tryed to highlight what I'm trying to fix, I hope this is more understandable!

Comment: I think Daniel's answer is correct. Also - you might find [boost.m4](https://github.com/tsuna/boost.m4/wiki) to be more useful than the autoconf archive macros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the macro `BOOST_ENABLE_ASSERT_HANDLER` is somehow being defined.

As stated in [the documentation for Boost.Assert](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/utility/assert.html), if `BOOST_ENABLE_ASSERT_HANDLER` is defined when `<boost/assert.hpp>` is included, then `BOOST_ASSERT(expr)` expands to a call to `boost::assertion_failed`, but *this function is not implemented*; the user is expected to provide an implementation.

Try to see if something is causing `BOOST_ENABLE_ASSERT_HANDLER` to be defined when building check_PROGRAMS.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're right, however the documentation does not provide any sample implementation...
Anyway thx again guys!

Comment: Our projects apparently have this defined, but in a library such that linker order is critical and I needed circular library includes.  Thanks!